Unable to deploy program to mainnet using solana cli `1.17.31`
I tried to deploy my program to mainnet but i keep getting the following error.
Error: Error processing Instruction 3: invalid account data for instruction

i have allocated twice the size of program but still get the above error. I can deploy the program on devnet and localnet. I am wondering what might be the issue.

Could you add as much info as you have? Did a deploy fail before? Can you send the address of the buffer account? Which version did you use to delpoy? 1.18.12 with --use-rpc flag is the most reliable at the moment probably. It may be that its trying to reuse a buffer account or smth.

Looks like you are using a syscall that is not activated on mainnet yet. Blake3.
You can see all used calls using:
 ~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/sdk/sbf/scripts/dump.sh solana_ibc.so output.txt

You can test it locally by disabling the feature thats not available.
solana-test-validator -r --deactivate-feature HTW2pSyErTj4BV6KBM9NZ9VBUJVxt7sacNWcf76wtzb3

